# jquery event.preventDefault() issues with IE 8

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery, preventdefault

In my jquery autocomplete `select` function, I need to use the `event.preventDefault()` method to prevent the default `ui.item.value` from populating the input text box the autocomplete is wired too. This works great in Chrome, however in IE 8 (which is in use by a majority of our users) the `.preventDefault()` line throws the following error:

```
Unexpected call to method or property access
```

Here is the jQuery for good measure. Does anyone know of a work-around for this method in IE 8?

```
var tempResults = [];
$(function () {
    $('#DRMCompanyName').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("compSearchByName", "AgentTransmission")',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: request,
                success: function (data) {
                    tempResults = data;
                    response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                        return {
                            label: value + " " + key, 
                            value: key
                        };
                    }));
                },
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault(); // <-Causing a problem in IE 8...
            $('#DRMCompanyName').val(tempResults[ui.item.value]);
            $('#DRMCompanyName').text(tempResults[ui.item.value]);

            if ($('#DRMCompanyId').text() == '') {
                $('#DRMCompanyId').val(ui.item.value);
                $('#DRMCompanyId').text(ui.item.value);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: same behaviour with return false;  (put at the end of handler of course)?

Comment: That worked, feel free to add as an answer if you want.

Comment: return false; does not equal return event.preventDefault(). event.preventDefault() will stop event propagation. Not sure if you need it, but just FYI

Comment: @mike.tihonchik this is the opposite, return false = event.preventDefault() + event.stopPropagation()

Comment: @roasted my point was, he used event.preventDefault(). So in the scenario where he would rely on events to propogate up the DOM, using return false; would not produce desired results

Comment: @mike.tihonchik ok so i think you havv made a typo when you said: "event.preventDefault() will stop event propagation"

Answer (score 1):

You could use `return false` instead but as i said in comment:  `return false = event.preventDefault() + event.stopPropagation()`  But in your case, should fit your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately our QA found this does not work on IE 8. I accidentally tested it on IE 9 yesterday.